# Different Cursor Options Questions

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor

Using a Cursor how can I get the following values?

```
Last Record
Next Record
Previous Record
Total Records
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Total records can be achieved using select @@cursor_rows within the cursor.
2. Next record can be achieved using "Fetch Next from "Cursor Name" into "variable"
3. Previous value can be achieved by assigning the current value into a variable other wise the next record from above statement will override it
4. Based on the @@cursor_rows you can determine whether you are at the last row or not.

Hope this helps!